# Dynamically generating FormFlow from JSON file

Tags: json, botframework

I am try to utilize JSON data to dynamically generate a form flow. In the Improved Sandwich Bot, each field in the form flow is independent to each other. For example, no matter I choose what kind of sandwich, I can continue to choose any type of bread. The only way to add some customization is using the following code:

```
.Field(new FieldJson(schema, "Specials")
    .SetType(null)
    .SetActive((state) => (string)state["Length"] == "FootLong")
    .SetDefine(async (state, field) =>
    {
        field
            .AddDescription("cookie", "FreeCookie")
            .AddTerms("cookie", "cookie", "FreeCookie")
            .AddDescription("drink", "FreeDrink")
            .AddTerms("drink", "drink", "FreeDrink");
        return true;
    }))
```

However, since different sandwich stores have different menus, the dependency between different fields varies a lot. For example,

> Store A may say only Sandwich1 can have toppings1, 2, 3. And store B
>   may say only Bread1 can have cheese1, 2, 3.

So I don't want to use the code above to implement the logic. It is not scalable.

So is it possible to include those dependency relations in the JSON file? In that way, the form builder can directly build the form flow with certain dependency relation.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible at this point but it seems like a very good suggestion. You can give the feedback at https://feedback.botframework.com/.